# I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?

Tags: discussion, faq, tags, tag-creation

I want to ask a question about game X, but this is the first time anyone asks about X so there's no corresponding [X] tag, and my reputation is too low to create a new tag. How should I tag it?

Comment: If your question is about the site (i.e. bugs, feature requests, discussion on site policies, tagging, etc) then this is the right place to post it.

Answer (score 29):

## State the game name clearly in your title and question body.

In the meantime, put some tags that **do** exist: platform, genre, and/or any other related tags.

You don't need to be obnoxious with a loud *"PLEASE TAG THIS"* message, having the game name in the question is often sufficient: the people who [can re-tag very easily](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) often notice when a question about a game has the platform and genre tags but not the game title, and will spring into action and re-tag the question appropriately.

If no-one has edited your post with the game tag in a couple of days, you can [ask someone in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), or [flag your post for moderator attention](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/i-want-to-ask-a-question-about-a-game-which-has-no-tag-yet-how-should-i-tag-it/814#814), with a custom reason asking for the tag to be created.

---

Note: In the spirit of keeping the tagging system as referring to the content of the questions, we should try to minimize the amount of "system" tagging on the main site. So we shouldn't opt for something like `[tag-this-game]` or any similar solution.

Another note: If the tag for your game doesn't exist, but a tag for one of its predecessors or sequels does, please don't use the wrong tag. Just make sure your question clearly states the name of the game you are playing, and you may opt to clarify at the end to establish which specific version you're asking about. But adding the wrong tag will simply invite trouble and make a mess out of things. Replacing a tag versus adding a tag is no difference in work, but the latter won't be giving false pretenses to other users.

Answer (score 13):

You can flag your post for moderation attention, and specify which game it is about in the detailed flagging message.

Comment: You still need to ask the question first, which requires at least one existing tag. Please clarify your answer to specify how to determine which such existing tag is best.

Answer (score 8):

Tags can't be created without questions, just ask your question and use an irrelevant tag and add a comment asking for a user to add the proper tag.

Comment: Preferably use a tag that gets close, but the end result will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

A tag cannot exist without a question. If you have a question about said game, just ask it and tag it with pc or something, but *do* mention in your post about what game you are talking, so someone with enough rep can add the tag to your question.

Comment: Leaving a comment on your own question with "can someone add the tag `[x]` for me" usually works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think after making a question you can flag it for moderator attention with the other reason and then just ask them to make the tag.

Apparently >300 rep users can make tags: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

So as Robotnik mentioned, just leave a comment asking someone to create a tag.