# How to differentiate old games (Starcraft vs Starcraft II)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just bought Starcraft/Broodwar, and I've been asking questions about it, but there's a strong tendency to get Starcraft II questions since it's so popular right now. Right now I use a disclaimer like:

> Note: This is referring to the 1998 game, not the current one.

Is this necessary, or is there a better way to identify the older variant of the game?

---

Related: [What is the Eraser Trick in StarCraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/what-is-the-eraser-trick-in-starcraft)

Comment: Given that I'm blind, I don't mind!

Answer (score 9):

This is common to happen any time a sequel or series-continuation is recently released. All you need to do as a question author is make sure you state the name of the game you are playing, and tag it appropriately. If you don't have the reputation to create a new tag, [see this FAQ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/i-want-to-ask-a-question-about-a-game-which-has-no-tag-yet-how-should-i-tag-it).

While it sometimes will help to add a notice explaining which game you are referring to, this is ultimately redundant noise as the game you're talking about should already be *clearly established by your question body and tags*.

It's also an ephemeral problem - once the immediate popularity dies down, the "notice" becomes worthless and tiresome noise to deal with. So having those warnings means that a few months down the line, we're going to need to go back through all of them and remove it. Unless we want to go back and start adding these to questions about [Assassin's Creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed), [Ogre Battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogre-battle), and every other non-most-recent iteration.

---

If someone answers your question with non-applicable content from the wrong game, it is no less off-topic if the game is part of the same series than if it was a completely different game. Comment them explaining that your question is explicitly tagged for the earlier game, and throw in a downvote if you don't feel merciful. It's unwanted noise, so don't feel bad about downvoting in this situation because that is exactly the kind of thing downvotes are used for.

Answerers should be giving the benefit of the doubt to the way that the question author phrases the question, instead of assuming that the author *must* be mistaken. To be honest, it's very rude to disregard what the author has clearly written and tagged.

[If you think the author is very likely to be referring to the wrong game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/how-do-i-get-past-the-labion-root-monster-in-space-quest-ii), then the better option should be to add a comment asking to verify the game. If the verification clears, then you can post your answer (maybe store it in Notepad while waiting?). If the verification doesn't clear, then at least now you don't have to sit with a downvoted answer for being off-topic.

Comment: I agree that adding "I'm referring to the older game" notices is noise (so +1), though I think it's pretty harmless. Still, I wouldn't add such a notice to my questions - just try to be very clear about the game in question and it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't somebody with enough reputation create a "Starcraft-Brood War" or "Brood War" tag?

Comment: You can ask a question about it, and then ask someone to create the tag on it for you.  That generally works pretty well.

Comment: Can somebody explain the -1 so I know what to consider avoiding in the future?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'm guessing it was because your "answer" doesn't really address the question of how we should differentiate between SC1 and SC2.  Also, downvotes work a little differently on Meta.  They don't affect your reputation at all, so don't worry about them too much.

Comment: @bwarner where should I place the request to make a new tag? In Gaming or Gaming Meta?

Comment: Tags get "created" when they are used for the first time.  If you have a question and want to put a new tag on it, but don't have enough rep to do so, just create the question and then add a comment to it specifying the tag that you would like created and added to the question.  Some higher rep user will then take care of it for you.

Comment: I think a Brood War tag is an excellent solution.