# Should I specifically tag if a game is on a mobile device?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I have asked a few questions regarding mobile device games and I have been inclined to tag with the "Mobile" tag.

The reason for my choice is because with such a massive mobile market and countless different games (with more being released daily) I felt the need to make it clear that my questions regard a mobile game.

However, upon using the "Mobile" tag I have noticed that it is rarely used at all, which of course has let me to believe it is not common practice, and thus this question here.

I am happy to not include such a tag in the future if that is the general agreement here, but the problem I find is as follows:

I am currently not at the 300 Rep mark and cannot therefore create my own tags. With the mobile market so quick to develop new games, it is going to be common place for people to ask questions about new games. In this case, the tag may not be available, so what should be used to tag for users with lower than 300 rep? (because obviously it is required for a minimum of one tag to be selected)

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless

Comment: For what it's worth, you are over the 300 rep mark now, and congratulations! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer, no you should not.

As a longer answer, [mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile) is even less useful than a platform tag, and [we aren't convinced those are useful](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless). Knowing that a game is on a mobile device is too coarse grained to provide any meaningful information to the people viewing and answering the question.  Basically, for new mobile games, either the person viewing the question knows the game (and therefore knows that it is a mobile game) or they know nothing about it, so they just ignore the question and go on to the next one.

As far as new users asking questions about new games, I don't think we have an official policy on what tag they should use, as we're pretty good about editing in a proper tag in a short time frame.  Getting new users to even realize there is a FAQ, let alone a standard tag to use when one doesn't exist, is probably an exercise in futility.  I don't have a problem with low rep users grabbing whatever tag they want.  It will get fixed pretty fast.