# Why is there a [flash] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What value does adding the tag [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) have?

Other games aren't tagged with the technology used to make them.

It seems to me that if there has to be an additional tag it should be [browser-based](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-based).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

The [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag should be used the same way as platforms tags, as outlined in [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless).

Comment: We kept all of the other platform tags. Why should we get rid of this one?

Comment: @murgatroid99: We only use platform tags for things exclusive to that platform and `technical-issues`.

Comment: I was more thinking that the tag should really be [tag:browser-based] rather than being removed completely.

Comment: We have flash + technical issues: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32257/why-are-my-flash-game-saves-getting-erased

Comment: @ChrisF: browser-based isn't any better than flash. Read LessPops meta if you already haven't.

Comment: @murgatroid99: I didn't notice that question. I thought all current uses of the tag were being used to denote the game was a flash game. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @murgatroid99: Yeah, which I think `flash` should be good for.

Answer (score 0):

It exists because tags used to be removed if there weren't two questions with that tag, which flash questions usually wouldn't get. Now that that's been disabled for us, there's no further use for the [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag.