# How should we tag the Xbox 360 and PS3 versions of the same game?

Tags: discussion, tags

Terraria was just released for the Xbox 360 and PS3, with a lot more features than the PC version, and it will be getting more. As far as I know, the base mechanics are the same, but it's been updated past the PC version. To make things worse, [the PC version may get new updates](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/something-about-a-possible-pc-update.95324/) which might not be the same as the console ones, creating things that only exist in the PC version and other things that only exists in the 360/PS3 version.

How should we go about tagging the different versions now?

Comment: I think I'm leaning more toward your suggestion for the [terraria-console] tag.

Answer (score 8):

First off, I don't know much about Terraria, so I can't speak to the specifics of this case, but this has come up a few times, so here's a short guide to What To Do About Games with Variable Versions:

- If the multiple releases are essentially just ports with small feature or UI differences, or the inclusion of bonus content such as the various reissues of *Final Fantasy 6*, you should note any platform specific restrictions *in the body or title of the question*. Platform tags should not be used.
- If the multiple releases are substantially different games that share a large amount in common, but are fundamentally not the same, such as the DS (and later iOS) remake of *Final Fantasy 4*, then those versions which were released *after* the original/canonical version should be tagged with a variant game-specific tag, noting the new edition in question. Another good example of this is [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), as the Minecraft ports are mechanically quite different. Tagging with the source game *as well* might be wise as well, but is at your discretion.
- If the question is about how a port interacts with the *hardware of a specific platform*, platform tags may be called for.

Comment: At this point I actually agree more with this than my own answer, but I still find my viewpoint to be fair so I'll leave it around.

Comment: PS3 and Xbox versions of Terraria should have the tag [terraria-console]. While Terraria changes significantly across versions, the console version is the same between the differant platforms.

http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/what-happened-to-the-terraria-console-tag

Answer (score 0):

I'd think we just tag them with [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria), and if the question is about features that are specific to the 360 or PS3 versions, we would add the appropriate platform tags as well. Likewise, once the PC version has its own exclusive features that aren't in the others, questions about those exclusive features would warrant the PC tag. Questions that are applicable to both with little or no significant difference, wouldn't need any secondary tags.

[Unless we are still keen on just not using platform tags in this fashion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless), in which case then we just wouldn't make any distinction *in tags*. Then we'd just put the relevant information in the question body.

I wouldn't suggest making some compound tag of `game-platform` in this kind of situation, especially when a lot of features are still shared. Then people who want to look for one, or the other, would have to search through both tags in order to see things that are relevant to just one of them.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't [`minecraft-xbox`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) also be reconsidered?

Comment: @FEinchinger I don't know at this point. There's two possible ways this goes and apparently no one is sure which one Terraria is. You can have something like [tag:spelunky], in which the alternate version is an extremely revamped port, but still a *port*, or you have summat like Minecraft which, as LessPop put it, is substantially different that "port" would be inaccurate. This answer assumes the former situation.