# Should there be a diablo-3-console tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some major gameplay differences between the console and PC versions of Diablo-3.  According to [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4639/3062), should those questions be tagged [diablo-3-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-console) instead?

Example question: [What effect does difficulty have on the console version of Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130345/what-effect-does-difficulty-have-on-the-console-version-of-diablo-3)

Comment: We could start adding platform tags, but that would mean going back and adding [tag:pc] to every existing Diablo 3 question.

Comment: @MichaelDunfield That is a terrible idea. That's not a good use of the platform tags. Separate tags for different versions of the game make much more sense, like the way we do with Minecraft Pocket Edition.

Comment: I stand corrected.  And now that I think about it again, you're right, that's not what platform tags are for.

Comment: Maybe just tag such a question with `diablo-3` and `ps3`?

Comment: @user1306322 nope, there are 2 arguments against that.  The first one is in the meta post I referenced.  The second is the fact that diablo-3 console is also available on the xbox-360.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes.

Diablo III is not a game that was released on multiple platforms, it was a PC Game that was re-released for consoles as a separate, standalone game.

It's also (at times) radically different from the PC game. Off the top of my head:

- offline play
- no auction house
- split-screen loot
- loot 2.0
- difficulty changes
- etc.

Will there be some overlap? Yes, most assuredly, but this version of the game, like Minecraft Pocket Edition, definitely warrants its own tag.

Comment: Loot 2.0 will guaranteed be part of the PC version.  When asking questions about that (after PC gets patched), should we use the diablo-3 tag, diablo-3-console, or both?

Comment: @fbueckert Please don't take consider that list the only valid topics for the `Diablo-3-console` tag. That said, in cases where there *are* overlap, I believe that the PC tag should be preferred.

Comment: @fbueckert They've already confirmed that even after the update, PC loot won't be exactly the same as console loot.

Comment: I can only see this working IF AND ONLY IF it is a feature/issue with a gamepad/console.

Comment: An even better example IMO is Minecraft (PC) vs Minecraft (XBox). Technically the same game, but one is a console port. And the XBox one gets its own tag even though it is specifically being updated to match the PC one, because nevertheless it is a different game, and there are fundamental differences.

Answer (score -2):

No alternative answer to vote up? Going to play devil's advocate here :)

## No.

- The vast majority of game mechanics, affixes, bosses etc. do not differ from the PC version. A console tag will invite duplicates & confusion for users searching for this information.
- Offline play and no AH are not significant in terms of questions asked : all it means is that all questions on AH only apply to PC version, and having to remember that PC version needs internet connection.
- The actual console specific questions are more on the lines of 'how does this differ from PC game', not standalone questions solely applicable to the platform.

Comment: It has been announced that they will be removing the AH from the PC version. So there will be even fewer significant differences.

Comment: @ColinD - wow that's good news, though it might be too late ... would be great if they added a new server after closing AH for a clean economy!