# Revisit Smash Bros 4 tag

Tags: discussion

There are huge fundamental differences already known between the 3ds and WiiU version of Smash Bros 4 tag. The [previous meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-to-tag-smash-bros-4?rq=1) indicates we'd like to stick with `smash-bros-4`, but since there are fundamental differences, including ui, gamemmodes, matchmaking, characters, I think it's far better if we had different separate tags.

See: http://www.ssbwiki.com/Cross-platform_comparison_of_Super_Smash_Bros._4

> Notable differences:
>
> - Both versions have Classic Mode.
>
>   - However, the **mode is vastly different between versions.**
> - Both versions have All Star Mode.
>
>   - However, the order the characters are **faced is different** between versions.
> - Both versions have Target Blast.
>
>   - However in the Wii U version, the second bomb is bigger and there will be **three different maps**
>
> A majority of stages seemingly will be exclusive to one version or the
>   other. The 3DS version will feature **more stages from handheld
>   games**, while the Wii U version will feature more stages from console
>   games as well **as more stages in general**. Even the two games'
>   versions of Battlefield, while possibly identical in physics, will be
>   different in aesthetics.[2] The WiiU version will also have **larger
>
> ## stages such as Big Battlefield to allow for  8 player Smash**
>
> **The Wii U version includes Stage Builder, which has been overhauled since its appearance in** Brawl.
>
> - **Smash Run is unique to the 3DS version.**
> - **Smash Tour, Events, Special Smash, Stage Builder, and Special Orders are all unique** to the Wii U version.

I think you can see how annoying it would be to hunt through each question to find the "well, this is actually for WiiU/3DS" tidbit, instead of having a tag that instantly allows us to figure out which version they may be talking about.

Comment: As you can see it's no longer just a small difference in mechanics such as between tf2-console and tf2-pc, it's huge fundamental differences

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's have a look at all the SSB4 questions we currently have.

- [What exactly do all of Shulk's different modes do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193119/what-exactly-do-all-of-shulks-different-modes-do)
- [Is there any way to control how fast Wild Gunman fires with Duck Hunt's Down B?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192995/is-there-any-way-to-control-how-fast-wild-gunman-fires-with-duck-hunts-down-b)
- [How do I not get kicked for targeting a single opponent?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192971/how-do-i-not-get-kicked-for-targeting-a-single-opponent)
- [Can screen rumbling/shaking be turned off in Smash Bros Wii U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192745/can-screen-rumbling-shaking-be-turned-off-in-smash-bros-wii-u)
- [Can I use Amiibo as a playable character in Smash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192587/can-i-use-amiibo-as-a-playable-character-in-smash)
- [Which items are considered battering items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188833/which-items-are-considered-battering-items)
- [Are there any tricks to Rival Smash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188190/are-there-any-tricks-to-rival-smash)
- [What character / attack / stage combination can get me a combo of 100?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188137/what-character-attack-stage-combination-can-get-me-a-combo-of-100)
- [What factors into the score in Classic Mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186815/what-factors-into-the-score-in-classic-mode)
- [Will something bad happen if I finish the Master Core too slowly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186726/will-something-bad-happen-if-i-finish-the-master-core-too-slowly)
- [Does riding Lloid cause it to deal more damage on impact?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186664/does-riding-loid-cause-it-to-deal-more-damage-on-impact)
- [How can I tell which characters can equip which custom parts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186402/how-can-i-tell-which-characters-can-equip-which-custom-parts)
- [Why should I keep punching the bombs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186279/why-should-i-keep-punching-the-bombs)
- [What exactly does "Speed" affect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186276/what-exactly-does-speed-affect)
- [How do I change the text for taunts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186093/how-do-i-change-the-text-for-taunts)
- [What strategy will get the most distance for Home Run Contest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186041/what-strategy-will-get-the-most-distance-for-home-run-contest)
- [Can I trade Trophies with friends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186004/can-i-trade-trophies-with-friends)
- [Why do Master Balls "almost always" have a legendary Pokemon in them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184633/why-do-master-balls-almost-always-have-a-legendary-pokemon-in-them)
- [What determines how many smash coins I get at the end of a match?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184632/what-determines-how-many-smash-coins-i-get-at-the-end-of-a-match)

  - Might be written for one version in particular, but should (in theory) be the same across both versions.
- [How do I create a separate account in Smash for Wii U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192713/how-do-i-create-a-separate-account-in-smash-for-wii-u)

  - Wii U-specific.
- [How do I unlock all of the stages in Smash Bros for Wii U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-do-i-unlock-all-of-the-stages-in-smash-bros-for-wii-u)
- [Is there a bonus for collecting all the items in the 8-player classic Donkey Kong level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192698/is-there-a-bonus-for-collecting-all-the-items-in-the-8-player-classic-donkey-kon)

  - Related to Wii U-exclusive stages.
- [Stage Builder, do you get more parts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192518/stage-builder-do-you-get-more-parts)

  - Clearly Wii U-exclusive feature (Stage Builder).
- [What does leveling an amiibo in Smash 4 do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193135/what-does-leveling-an-amiibo-in-smash-4-do)

  - Wii U-specific for now, but will be shared across both versions in future (3DS is confirmed to get amiibo support later).
- [Are there any secret areas in Smash Run?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188295/are-there-any-secret-areas-in-smash-run)
- [What are the white lines in the Smash Run result screen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186316/what-are-the-white-lines-in-the-smash-run-result-screen)

  - Clearly 3DS-exclusive feature (Smash Run).
- [What does "Get a total of 5 hits in StreetSmash" mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186222/what-does-get-a-total-of-5-hits-in-streetsmash-mean)

  - Clearly 3DS-exclusive feature (StreetPass).
- [Is there a way to see what modes I've cleared?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186822/is-there-a-way-to-see-what-modes-ive-cleared)
- [How does Conquest Mode work in Super Smash Bros. Direct?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186181/how-does-conquest-mode-work-in-super-smash-bros-direct)
- [Are all Omega stages the same length?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184165/are-all-omega-stages-the-same-length)
- [What gameplay mechanics are new to Super Smash Bros 3DS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184119/what-gameplay-mechanics-are-new-to-super-smash-bros-3ds)

  - 3DS-specific question and answer, but can be tweaked/expanded to cover Wii U as well.
- [Can I adjust item frequency?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186275/can-i-adjust-item-frequency)
- [Have two shield buttons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185993/have-two-shield-buttons)
- [Can I use the D-Pad to move around?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185647/can-i-use-the-d-pad-to-move-around)
- [How do you unlock all of the characters in SSB4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184404/how-do-you-unlock-all-of-the-characters-in-ssb4)

  - 3DS-specific; the Wii U version would have a different answer, which isn't 100% clear.
- [Are there any secret taunts in Super Smash Bros 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184634/are-there-any-secret-taunts-in-super-smash-bros-4)

  - The answer is "yes" for both versions, but the specifics are different.

So. That's **19** questions (52%) that are version-agnostic, **5** (14%) that are (currently) clearly Wii U-specific, **3** (8%) that are clearly 3DS-specific, **4** (11%) that are written for 3DS but could work for Wii U given a bit of editing, and **5** (14%) that have potential for version confusion.

If 75%+ of current questions are non-ambiguous, I don't think we need to mess with the tagging.

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous consensus still stands.  Even with the differences you mention, it's not very different from [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) [version differences](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Differences_between_platforms), which we only have a single game tag for.  Consider the following:

- Stage Builder for WiiU Smash is no different than custom maps in PC TF2
- Event matches are not much different than achievements that are only in PC TF2
- Going from 4 to 8 player smash is no different than 16 to 32 max players
- Having Classic/All-Star modes be different is similar to having different counts for ammo or levels for dispensers/teleporters

The point is, TF2 is a game that features version differences similar to the ones you mentioned for Smash, yet we only have a single game tag for TF2.  For questions that need a system clarified, as @RavenDreamer points out in [his comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-to-tag-smash-bros-4?rq=1#comment27773_9973),

> Tag the system if your question is system specific.

Comment: Why are you comparing this to TF2? I thought we were comparing the 3DS version to WiiU.

Comment: @memescientist Because the TF2 tag is in a similar boat.  The PC version is very different from the console versions, but we only have a common team-fortress-2 tag rather than one for pc, another for ps3, and another for xbox

Comment: TF2 is no way close to Smash, please don't compare apples to oranges. It's all fine if you compare Tf2 - console to Tf2 - PC, but why you are comparing Tf2 PC to Smash WiiU makes no sense to me

Comment: @memescientist No one said TF2 is close to Smash.  I'm saying the tagging issue is similar for both.  They are both games that have version differences.  Taking TF2 as a historical example provides a continuity for us to take with Smash tagging.

Comment: "*Stage Builder for WiiU Smash is no different than custom maps in PC TF2 / Event matches are not much different than achievements that are only in PC TF2 / Going from 4 to 8 player smash is no different than 16 to 32 max players*" No, you are comparing TF2 to smash.

Comment: @memescientist You seem to be missing the point.  Just because a game has differences between systems does not make it a new game requiring a new tag.  TF2 is a game that has many version differences, yet it does not have separate tags for the different systems.  Smash 4 has version differences, but paralleling the differences to some of the ones in TF2, we can see that there is nothing you mentioned in Smash that requires us to separate it into multiple games.

Comment: oh really? Not including 8 player smash,  smash tour, events, special smash, stage builder, special orders, different stages, different all-star matchups, different character unlock requirements, different classic mode content, different target blast mode? Yeah, you're completely right, there's like NO difference between the 3ds and the WiiU version.

Comment: I see this as being more akin to [tag:minecraft] and [tag:minecraft-console]; there are significant enough differences in my opinion to warrant a separate tag. Normally, I'd be in support of a platform-agnostic tag, however, it's becoming clear that this is a special case.

Comment: It is a good representation, but if you look back at it, the console versions and the PC version all started out, relatively the same. As time progressed though, and more users played on PC, the updates went only there, compared the minuscule amount of players on the consoles. Point 1 - Due to the fact that they started out the same, they can follow the same tag. Point 2 - I do not think there are enough console users to make it seem like there could be problems identifying the two. But, Smash Bros for the 3DS and for the Wii U started as totally different games, with only some similarities.

Comment: But, then again, questions for one can usually apply to the other. And if it really comes down to the poster really wanting a identifier that this is for the 3DS version but no the Wii U, they could add the extra tag for 3DS to it, or vise versa. So in the end, I don't the tag needs to be changed. There are enough differences between them, that just in the question can answer which one they refer to, and an extra tag can confirm it. And if it really comes down to it, someone trying to answer it can ask the poster, or post an answer that would work for both, if the question was broad enough.

Comment: Is the added console tag an appropriate use of those tags though? I thought the console tags were for use when you have a question about the console itself not as a marker for what console a game is on. Shouldn't this be treated more as Pokemon-xy and Pokemon-sixth-gen?

Comment: @Reafexus According to [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4639/42984) "**Platform Tags should henceforth only be used for questions specifically about a given platform or console, or a game's interaction with that platform or console**".  While I disagree with this, it is accepted by the community so we should respect it.  In regards to where the system is mentioned, the answer says: "**Questions about a specific version or port of that game should not be tagged based on the platform, but should instead make a note of the version in question in the body of the question**"