# How do we tag multiplatform games?

Tags: discussion, tags, gaming-hardware

I couldn't find this question asked before even though it seems like an important decision to me:  How do we tag a question that may or may not have different answers depending on platform?  The most recent relevant multiplatform game of note is The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild which came out simultaneously on Wii U and the Nintendo Switch.

From observation, it appears that we don't include a console tag if the question isn't console-specific which, since this particular game is a direct port as far as I know, is usually the case.  However, there are some questions [like this one about save files](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301983/is-there-a-way-to-have-multiple-players-save-sets-in-zelda-breath-of-the-wild) that could *potentially* be console-specific, yet happens to have the same answer for both consoles.  Should we include both console tags if the answer works either way, remove the tag because that's our convention, or leave it as is because of the original intent of the question and answer?

Comment: instead of using tags to say which platform you are using, you could just write it into the question itself

Comment: Related https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the linked meta, I, too, support the exclusion of the console tag from questions about multi-platform games.

The issue with giving console tags to questions that *may* have different answers based on consoles is that someone seeking an answer for a different console will likely not look at the original question and ask another for a different console (even if the answer covers all consoles).

For nearly all cases, if the console seems important to a question, ***mention it in the question***. (I said nearly all with the intent of proposing a counter-example, but I can't think of a good one.)

Furthermore, if there *are* different answers for different consoles, I would even say that the *best* answer should cover *all* consoles to keep all the information in one place.

Comment: Plus, if it turns out the console is important to the question and the question doesn't make sense with other consoles, we can always add the tag later.

Comment: @Vemonus Won't that somewhat force people into creating "duplicate" questions for other versions of the game?

Comment: @Oak not at all. Tagging with the specific console would cause that.

Comment: @Vemonus True, but at their core they would be different (because the answer required is different). If there's only one question, Ideally the best answer would cover all consoles, but it's not always possible. However answering for one console when it was asked for another would technically be Not Answering the question, which could deter people from answering for consoles other than the specified. Also, what if another user wants to know for another console? He can't edit the Original question (because it would conflict with the author), yet he can't ask it (since it would be a dupe), right?

Comment: @Oak I'm not really seeing your argument here. Why would we delete an answer that addresses multiple (ideally all) consoles as not answering the question?

Comment: @Oak I meant one that does't answer all consoles. For example, if I were to ask something regarding PS2 (assuming that all versions are different), and you'd answer for PC, you wouldn't be answering my question. Not that I'm against doing that, but I'm looking for some clarification

Comment: @Oak I didn't mean to remove the console from the question, only the tags. The question could still specify a console and the answers should still answer for that console, however, the *best* answer would mention fixes or solutions relevant for other consoles. It's not a requirement, but it would be helpful. That way, there's no need for the console-specific tag. I've seen plenty of examples where a question asks how to do something on one system, the accepted answer answers for that system, but other, upvoted answers tell how to do it for other systems.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to get to: The case where the answer isn't for the asked platform, but for another platform.

Comment: @Oak they're still useful, as long as the original platform's been answered for.