# Questions regarding new tags for extra long tags

Tags: discussion

So I have a question to ask about an unlisted game and as recommended I should create a tag for said game. (I didn't know that different SE sites had different reputation requirements. I'm mostly used to StackOverflow where it's 1500 currently.)

I want to ask about the "Who Wants To Be A Millionaire: Special Editions" game. I know it's not a popular game but as its a game, and there are several meta topics about avoiding just using the console tag (SEE: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/21481), I figured I'd go and make one. But as `millionaire-special-editions` seems exceptionally long, I was wondering if it was acceptable or if I should consider a shorter tag.

Comment: You can actually create the tag yourself since you have 300 rep (though there is a 25 character limit on tags, so the question is how should that be handled since this is definitely over 25 characters)

Comment: Yeah... "who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire" is about 30... So I guess just use "millionaire" as a tag? I didn't know 300 rep was okay for making tags. Guess I was used to StackOverflow's 1500 requirement. Figured that each site followed the same.

Comment: @PaulWilliams - SO has a lot more users and deals with a lot more questions than us. Raising the bar for them was a matter of maintaining site & tag quality. As for *Who Wants To Be a Millionaire?*, we could do `[millionaire]`, however a lot of descriptions online use 'wwtbam' or 'WWBM' to describe the show, so we could do a similar thing with `[wwtbam-special-editions]` or something like that as well.

Comment: I'm actually okay with `[WWTBAM]`. Do I also have the permissions to edit the tag descriptions so I can offer alternatives or is that another permission to? And curses the question got closed while I was editing.

Comment: @Paul - you can suggest tag descriptions which will be voted on accordingly :)

Comment: I would vote for [tag:wwtbam], given there is a game on the android marketplace specifically called [millionaire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=boyansoft.bogmix.eng.millionaire&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dgame+millionaire&pcampaignid=APPU_1_bvRLVtSZPOPlmAXq1KqQBQ)

Comment: Now that since that question is answered... the other question is still up... is there an appropriate SE for Game Shows (not necessarily the video games though)? Trying to see if it's appropriate if people should write questions here about questions/answers in the game.

Comment: @PaulWilliams I'm going to go with no on the grounds that 100% of the time it would be quicker and easier to google. Besides, the question would belong on the appropriate stack exchange for its subject.

Comment: @Studoku, If there is one. I'm not seeing anything relating to television directory outside of science fiction.

Comment: @PaulWilliams Why would it need to be Television? If the question was about geopgraphy, ask in geography. If it was about pasta, ask in cooking. And, as I said, since they're *always* googleable, just google it.