# Can we have a "rec-room" tag please?

Tags: support, tags

in the [rec room](https://recroom.com/rec-room/) community we want to try to use Arqade for frequently asked questions. Could you please create one, or tell me what to do to get it created? Thanks.

Comment: I'll not post this as an answer as I don't know our policy on using Arqade as an FAQ website (and that's IMO the main question that needs to be answered here), but a tag will be created as once a question is posted, either by asker if they have enough rep, or by an editor who has enough rep. You may also raise a mod flag on such a question asking for said role to be added, though just [asking in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) may also be sufficient as there's a large number of active high-rep users there, including myself.

Comment: Thanks for that. We are not trying to start an FAQ site, but redirect rec room "programming" questions that fit a Q&A style better here, than having them asked on discord or reddit repeatedly. I'll try the chat next, if this question doesn't help.

Comment: Also what is the actual difference between an FAQ site where people can ask questions on their own and a Q&A site like this?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/product-support

Comment: @SteakOverflow Well, I would say the difference is on the availability of the answer. FAQ or Frequently Asked Questions, is more for common stuff (as it's name stand for).
Meanwhile, I would use StackExchange for something more obscure, something that you can't find the answer in 5 minutes online or just reading the manual.

Comment: Looks like you guys are using multiple accounts to build up knowledge base, be aware of anti voting rings algorithms https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: @arghtype Thanks for the warning, but there isn't much we can do about that. We are encouraging people to create their own accounts. But naturally, most of the answers will come from a small set of people. We are not using multi-accounting or anything to boost scores or whatever you can attempt with that. But the people who come here for rec room will probably mostly interact with rec room questions, and only vote on each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Arqade!

There's nothing wrong with using us for your FAQ/Q&A efforts (in fact it's something that [we'd like to encourage](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13503/28182)). Just bear in mind that each question must be able to stand on it's own, and fit into our rules around what is [on or off-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The sorts of questions that would work best for us would most likely be gameplay-related. As you mention programming (I assume Rec Room uses a 'Roblox'-style approach to programming?), some questions may be a better fit for [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or even [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Also note that the questions should be reasonably scoped. For example, *"How do I build a Tetris clone in Rec Room?"* would be too broad, but *"How do I determine if an entire row is filled with blocks?"* should be ok.

As for creating the tag - tags cannot exist without a question to apply them to, and Stack Exchange requires users to have 300 rep to unlock tag creation privileges. Our community's workaround to this is covered in our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question: [I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/28182):

> ## State the game name clearly in your title and question body.
>
> In the meantime, put some tags that **do** exist: platform, genre, and any other related items. You don't need to be obnoxious with a loud "PLEASE TAG THIS", just having the game name is often sufficient: often times that the people who [can retag very easily](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13503/28182) notice when a question about a game has the platform and genre tags but not the game title, and will spring into action and retag the question appropriately.
>
> If noone has edited your post with the game tag in a couple of days, you can [ask someone in chat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), or [flag your post for moderator attention](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/i-want-to-ask-a-question-about-a-game-which-has-no-tag-yet-how-should-i-tag-it/814#814), with a custom reason asking for the tag to be created.

Let me know if you need any further information, and thanks for considering us for your FAQ efforts!

Comment: Thanks. So I I understand that correctly, we will start do post some questions and answers and have them tagged later. Let me also apologize for the confusion about the term "programming". It doesn't refer to any coding, all "scripting" is done with in-game circuits.

Comment: Ok cool. And yep that sounds fine to me :). Once one question is retagged to [rec-room], the tag counts as 'created' so you will be able to use it yourself for subsequent questions :)

Comment: rec room uses big "physical" blocks of code for programming, like scratch, and roblox uses solid code, so no, they are not similar in that way.