# Can we create a tag for Highfleet?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-creation

Game: [Highfleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HighFleet)

PC war strategy game set in a fictional universe.

My question which calls for the tag: [Precisely when will transport Hawk arrive at Goshen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398338/precisely-when-will-transport-hawk-arrive-at-goshen)

Thanks!

--

Note: the `[tag-creation]` entry says (emphasis mine):

> Questions about creating new tags. If your meta question is about needing a new tag for your question, first: **tag with the platform (such as [pc])** and state the game name clearly in your question title/body. Someone with the required reputation will edit your question to create the tag for you.

But there is no `[pc]` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/4797)

Comment: "But there is no [pc] tag." That's weird. The [[tag:pc]] tag exists and should be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag [highfleet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highfleet) has been created. Normally a moderator or community member will create a tag when asked for just as you did (it may take some time), so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Also, there is a [tag:pc] tag just to add!

Comment: I bet Gaming.Meta.SE has a different tag set than Gaming.SE. Anyhow -- thanks! :)